# Translate website with prefix URL when everything is on domain

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

The website I'm working on has multiple languages and the detection is based on domain name.

I want to add another language, available only to developers, but do not have a domain name for it now. So I would like to know if it is possible for ONE language to be found via prefix, an example structure would be:

- http://www.a.com (french)
- http://www.b.com (english)
- http://www.a.com/ru/ (russian)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

Not with the core code.

## Avaliable solutions

1. [Language Domains](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_domains) would allow you to create alternative domain prefixes, like ru.example.com and www.example.com leading to different languages.
2. [Domain Locale](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_locale) - this one I never used, but it promises to *"customize language sets per domain"*